# TYPO3 FormFactory how to access multiple values in custom validator?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

the task is pretty simple - we have 2 fields, one for startdate and the other for enddate. one custom validator works fine and validates that the startdate is in the future. the second custom validator should validate that the enddate is not before the startdate. so the validator needs both values, the startdate and the enddate.

we create the form within a FormFactory:

```
$page = $this->form->createPage('event');
$startDateEl = $page->createElement('start', 'Text');
$startDateEl->addValidator($this->futurestart);
$endDateEl = $page->createElement('end', 'Text');
$endDateEl->addValidator($this->endnoconflictstart);
```

these are the validators:

```
$this->futurestart = $this->objectManager->get(DateTimeFutureStartValidator::class);
$this->endnoconflictstart = $this->objectManager->get(DateTimeStartEndNoConflictValidator::class);
```

thats the second validator implementation:

```
namespace x\x\Validator;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class DateTimeStartEndNoConflictValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // validate stuff, addError, etc...
    }
}
```

how could i access "all" or a single other value from the form which got submitted?

help is much appreciated